# Why well-designed DynamoDB application require only one table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql

On Amazon DynamoDB help center I've [read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html)  that

> You should maintain as few tables as possible in a DynamoDB
>   application. Most well designed applications require only one table.

Sorry guys, but what does it mean? Whether should I design a database with just ONE table, or should I work with just one table in my (let it be php) application (but a database may contain several tables)?

Thank you!

Comment: Contrast the "well designed = one table" advice with the [Example Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.CreateTables.html#SampleData.CreateTables1) for Use Case 2 (Forum App), which clearly shows 3 different tables for one application.

Answer (score 1):

I think this One Table concept means if you draw a relational database diagram of your models and associations, then all associated tables that connected should be able to be merged, or designed into one single NoSQL table. If you got two sets of tables in the same relational database that have no association between them, then you can group them into two separate NoSQL tables.